# Selecting, sorting, and grouping spatial data (lines) by length and proximity

Tags: line, fme-form, proximity, length, sorting

I'm working on a project where I have a bunch of lines inside of polygonal land parcels. Here's a rough sketch of what I'm talking about:

[image: Lines inside polygon]

I need to further subdivide these parcels into sections that contain ~80km of line each while trying to maintain line connectivity as much as possible. So as an example, I'd want the finished subsections to look like this (very rough) sketch here, where the blue line represents the boundary of each subdivided polygon that contains ~80km of line:

[image: Grouped lines inside polygon]

I've tried a couple of FME solutions, but I wasn't able to get anything to take. My issue is I need to sort and group based on two values: connectivity AND length, and I'm struggling to think of an automated solution to do so.

Comment: This would be solvable with a python script, but you’d have to provide a sample of your line data

Comment: Are you allowing the clipping of the red lines as they cross the polygon boundary, or are they to be kept whole?

Comment: Are the red lines guaranteed to be all connected within a parcel? I think this is a "constrained graph partitioning" problem if you want some keywords to lookup...